# Which user (aside from root) can change file permissions in Linux?

Tags: files, permissions

Basically: when I, as non-root user, execute `chmod` on a file, when do I get "permissions denied" for that command, and when not? Which property of the file allows or forbids me to change permissions of it?

I assume it is the file-owner, asking here as I'm just struggling a bit to learn about the underlying basic concepts.

Comment: I think your comment is the answer I was looking for. I really had trouble to find out about that. But what is about the root directory? Only the root user can handle it?

Comment: @SatoKatsura: I don't think that it is sufficient to be owner of the directory the files resides in. I think you have to own the file, since the permissions are stored in the inode of the file, not in the directory structure. But you could delete a file that you do not own in a folder that you have write permissions on.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** If you want to run `chmod` on a file on GNU/Linux, you need to be root or the owner of the file.

From the [chmod(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html#DESCRIPTION) (chmod system call) manual page:

> The effective UID of the calling process must match the **owner of the
>   file**, or the process must be privileged (Linux: it must have the
>   **CAP_FOWNER** capability).

From the [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html#DESCRIPTION) manual page:

> **CAP_FOWNER**
>
> - Bypass permission checks on operations that normally require the filesystem UID of the process to match the UID of the file (e.g.,
>     chmod(2), utime(2)), excluding those operations covered by
>     CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE and CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH;
>     *[...]*

From the [setfacl(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfacl.1.html#DESCRIPTION) manual page:

> **PERMISSIONS**
>
> The file owner and processes capable of CAP_FOWNER are granted the
>   right to modify ACLs of a file. This is analogous to the permissions
>   required for accessing the file mode. (On current Linux systems,
>   **root is the only user** with the **CAP_FOWNER** capability.)